# SQL Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) (Restatement_Reason)

Tags: sql, powershell, bulkinsert

Hi all I have been getting the following error when trying to bulk load data into SQL with powershell:

> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 13651, column 201
>   (Restatement_Reason).

Do you have any idea what this could mean??

If you need more info I can post code/data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Its just a bulk insert. no problem with code. It works for hundreds of data files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the data you are trying to bulk insert. 
More specific, check row 13651 and column 201.

It propably means that the data in that location is too wide for the column you are trying to insert it into.

Comment: wow. I was looking at the wrong column for some time, it is very tough to manually read data files. I did not realize that (restatement reason) was actually the name of a column. Thanks